# how to show a jar in Html?

Tags: java, jar, web-content

I have a Jar and the Jar I need to display in Html inside tomcat. How can I do that ?

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <applet codebase="." code="App.jar"  archive="App.jar"
    width="740" height="400"></applet>  

</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to run in firefox and and getting " can not verify self-singed Deployment Rule Set Jar "

Comment: Applets are deprecated.

Comment: "Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)" 
See https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: Tomcat? Jar? You want this: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html  What you are trying is most likely the wrong approach.

Comment: i am trying to run in firefox and and getting " can not verify self-singed Deployment Rule Set Jar "

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with *need to display in Html*. Schould the code of a `main` executed?

Comment: what jar excecute that should be displayed in browser

Comment: You can not do it in this way

Comment: how to do that then ? :(

Comment: You want to start jar from browser?

Comment: yes , thats the goal

Answer (score 0):

You can run non-applet jar from browser using Java Web Start, but it will run out of browser window.
Example: https://dzone.com/articles/java-web-start-jnlp-hello

Comment: I mean, browser will start your jar, but application window will be the separated window.

Answer (score -2):

If your jar file is for Applet program then use applet tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp

Comment: the jar is not for Applet.

Comment: the jar is just an hello world thing